# crash happens while re-initializing a string object

Tags: c++, string

Request you to have a deep look at the string class program present below

```
class String{
private: int len;
         int size;
         char *p;
public:  
     int getlen()
     {
         return len;
     }
     int getsize()
     {
         return size;
     }
     char* getp()
     {
         return p;
     }
     String(char *p1=0)
     {
         cout<<"constructor called"<<endl;
         if(p1!=0)
         {
            len=strlen(p1);
            size=len+1;
            p=new char(sizeof(char)*(size));
            strncpy(p,p1,size);
         }
         else
         {
             len=size=0;
             p="";
         }
     }
     String(String &s1)
     {
         cout<<"copy constructor called"<<endl;
         if(&s1!=this)
         {
             cout<<"copy constructor called"<<endl;
             len=s1.getlen();
             size=len+1;
             p=new char(sizeof(char)*(size));
             //char *d=s1.getp();
             strncpy(p,s1.getp(),size);
         }
     }
     void display()
     {
         cout<<"string len="<<len<<endl;
         cout<<"string size="<<size<<endl;
         cout<<"string name="<<p<<endl;
     }
     ~String()
     {
         cout<<"destructor called"<<endl;
         if(strlen(p) >= 1)
         {
            cout<<"111"<<endl;
            delete []p;
         }
         //cout<<"destructor finished"<<endl;
     }
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  String s1;
  String s2("hello");
  s1.display();
  s2.display();
  s2=String("Hello World");
  s2.display();
  return 0;
}
```

Please look at the re-initialization line

```
     s2=String("Hello World");
```

**String("Hello World") will create a temporary String object and the it should call assignment operator. Since default assignment operator by compiler would do shallow copy, after the temporary String object goes out of scope the char pointer present in the String class would become NULL.**

I tried to overload the assignment operator as below

```
 String& operator =(String &s1)
 {
     cout<<"operator = called"<<endl;
     if(&s1!=this)
     {
         len=s1.len;
         size=s1.size;
         if(strlen(p)>=1)
              delete p;
         p=new char(sizeof(char)*size);
         strncpy(p,s1.getp(),size);
     }
     return *this;
  }
```

But it is giving error **no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘String’ and ‘String’)
  s2=String("World");**

Request you to compile the program after correcting 'operator=', because I doubt copy constructor might give any error..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: It seems that you want to do a deep copy using the = operator. Also, it should be const string because you don't change s1 reference.

Comment: The expression `new char(sizeof(char)*(size))` does *not* do what you expect it to. It will allocate a *single* `char` and initialize it to `sizeof(char)*(size)`.

Comment: Make your assignment operator take `const String&`

Comment: Side note: maintaining both `len` and `size` as member variables is completely redundant.

Comment: And in your copy-assignment operator, what if you assign to an empty string? Then `p` would be null and `strlen(p)` would be undefined behavior.

Comment: Evil code. Aside from the answer, (1) assigning a read only memory string literal to a `char*` is naughty, (2) you have a mismatched new[] and delete, (3) deleting read-only memory will not end well. You better rewrite that assignment operator. Writing string classes is not fun. Use `std::string`, or, if you want to know how it works then read a good book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problems is this line:

```
p=new char(sizeof(char)*(size));
```

You need to use square brackets instead:

```
p=new char[sizeof(char)*(size)];
          ^                   ^
```

Second, for your copy constructor and assignment operator, the argument type should be `const`-qualified references, aka `const String&`, not just `String&`. Also, as good practice, any methods that don't modify any member variables (such as `display` or `getp`) should have a `const` at the end of the function declaration (i.e. just before the `{`).

Comment: It's worth noting that with `p=new char(...)`, OP allocates a single `char` element and initializes it to the value of `size` (which is possibly truncated from `int` to `char`).

Comment: This is flaw in my program but still my question's answer is not provided

Comment: Try fixing the `const` problems I mentioned, and it should fix your error.

Comment: @SantoshSahu It's not clear what you're asking in the first place.